# Why are some episodes of TV shows omitted from streaming platforms?

Tags: distribution

I recently had a memory from a joke from an old episode of "I Love Lucy" (Season 5 Episode 22). I saw that the series was streaming on Hulu, but this particular episode is missing! In fact, it looks like many episodes are omitted from the platform.

I've seen this issue before. Why might this happen?

Comment: It's possible, without knowing the specific episode, that the content might not be appropriate for today's audience. Alternatively, there could be a rights issue, or even that the actual copy recording is not still in existence. We just don't know without specifics.

Comment: It would be a bummer if the streaming platforms were censoring releases without at least acknowledging they were doing so.

Comment: Hulu is a disney platform...so it‘s likely weird rights issues. I have this issue very often watching streaming services with older shows in europe.

Comment: Is it possible that recordings of those episodes no longer exist? I know many episodes of British TV shows from before about 1970 have been lost forever, because the BBC regularly wiped and re-used their tapes to cut costs, and home recording was rare back then. I don't know whether American TV shows suffer the same problem.

Comment: Reddit also has a thread about this. Some speculate that it may get down to the music rights, others claim racism/slurs (so censorship), and others argue licensing fees (ie: Hulu didn't want to pay for them all), but no one on there has a concrete answer either: https://www.reddit.com/r/Hulu/comments/esk63u/why_are_there_so_many_episodes_of_i_love_lucy/